# Xamarin Android C# Logging

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, dll

I´m about to finish my apprenticeship soon and I must do a project. I want to write a logging-class/-dll for being used by other programs. I will use Xamarin for android (C#) because my company will use my dll in the future for their apps.

My dll should contain log levels, for example if the developer wants the full path of actions the user did, or only if an error occurs he wants go get the errordata. The dll should be able to track more than only the error/errormessage (->which leads us to the logging levels).

Does anyone have an idea how to get into this topic or has any testfiles for me?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Questions of this nature are considered off topic or outside the scope of SO.  I have voted to close this question because of this, but please do not get discouraged. Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) about on topic questions. When you are stuck, come back and ask for help (in your case, as you start this project and you find a problem like "This bit of code keeps logging at level WARN but it should be logging level ERROR", that would most likely be a good question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are already few open source logging frameworks available that work on Xamarin.Android, e.g https://serilog.net/

There is another logging framework called NLog (https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/platform-support) You can refer these projects to build your own logging library

Comment: I already found NLog, but haven´t seen anything about serilog yet. Ty!

Comment: @Aazrail if the answer is correct or helped you, you should mark as the correct answer or upvote it